# Unshifting vs pushing on a v-for array

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, v-for, laravel-mix-vue3

I have a `laravel-mix vuejs` project

For some reason, I have a preview dialog that works by vanillajs instead of using `vuetify` or any other `VueJS UI Framework`.

**How the preview dialog works:**
**1**. A div with a class name of `preview-dialog` and a button with a class name of `trigger-preview-dialog`  gets rendered in the DOM.
**2**. A script script called `popup-dialog.js` gets loaded and assigns default stylings(`visibility: hidden`) to `preview-dialog` class.
**3**. When the `trigger-preview-dialog` gets clicked, it changes the `preview-dialog`'s `visibility` to `visible`.

Now, I have an array of `post_list` thats gets rendered by using `v-for directive` and its content is the `preview-dialog`.
and I also have a function that appends new object to `post_list`.

what I noticed is that, when I use `unshift` when appending new object to the `post_list`, the `preview_dialog` of the newly added object works fine and opens up. But when I use `push` when appending a new object, the newly added object' `preview_dialog` does not open at all and what's worse is that there're no errors I found on the chrome inspector.

Can someone enlighten me on why unshift works but push doesn't? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's all because of how vuejs track/observe object to be able to react to a change.

I would suggest to use the following syntax when working

- with array

```js
  
  addItem (item) {
    this.items = [...this.items, item]
```

- with object

```js
  
  updateItem (item) {
    this.item = Object.assign({}, this.item, item)
  }
```